# Keyboard media buttons Firefox

Tags: firefox, media, media-buttons

My keyboard has those nice media buttons - play/pause, next, back - that work for local players like Banshee. 
Is there any way to make them work in Firefox, like for Youtube videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally no. For a media player to be controllable using the media buttons on your keyboard it has to implement the [MPRIS specification](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/) which is not something a website can do. Also there is no way for a website to ask the browser to do that for it.

Alternatively an add-on could provide this functionality, but while it is [definitely possible](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/smart-pause-for-youtube/) to control YouTube playback from an add-on, there does not seem to by any add-on attempts to implement a MPRIS server for YouTube.

If you don't care about YouTube running in the browser you might want to give [MPS YouTube](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube#mps-youtube) a try.

All of this of course only applies to YouTube controlling other video/audio sites would of course require custom solutions for these sites as well.

Comment: Please upvote and mark as accepted answer if this helped you, but do ask for clarification if it did not!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, although it's not what I hoped to hear ;) mps youtube is interesting. I'll give it a try. But it only works with Python 3, so I'll have to find out how to  deal with this.

Comment: You don't *deal with* it using Python 3. ;-) Python 3 has been part of the default Ubuntu installation for [quite some time now](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#QuantalQuetzal.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Python_3.2). Basically installation should be as easy as running `sudo pip3 install mps-youtube` in some terminal window. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of extensions I found that control various sites from the keyboard

[Media Keys 0.5.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/media-keys/)

Lets you control Youtube, Pandora, Bandcamp and TidalHiFi website media players using the media keys on your keyboard.

[Be Quiet!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/be-quiet/?src=cb-dl-toprated)

Provides tool bar and keyboard media controls and more for several music sites. Adds automatic music pausing functionality when playing html5 videos or watching videos on Youtube.

[Google Music Media Key Fix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/google-music-media-key-fix/)

A fix to enable global use of media keys in Google Play Music.

I would think `media keys` is what you would need

Comment: Your first link doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Media keys only seem to work when the browser is the active window. I didn't write this in my answer, but I want this to work while I am using a different program in a different work space.

Comment: Sounds like that could be a bug in the extension, I would contact the developer https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/user/carlin-q/ as these are the only options I could find